# Find max value of a row in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I got a table like this

| Contract | value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 8 |
| A2 | 9 | 3 | 8 | 3 |

How can I find max value of 1 2 3 4 5 of each contract

| Contract | value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Maxvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 8 | 8 |
| A2 | 9 | 3 | 8 | 3 | 9 |

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a `VALUES` clause to unpivot the data and then get the `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT Contract,
       Value1,
       Value2,
       Value3,
       Value4,
       (SELECT MAX([Value])
        FROM (VALUES(Value1),
                    (Value2),
                    (Value3),
                    (Value4))V(Value)) AS MaxValue
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: can you explain why you use V(Value)? I don't get it.

Comment: @NamNguyen this is an article that may shed some light on what is being done here: https://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html

Comment: @Arie really appreciate.

Comment: They are aliases, @NamNguyen ,